# port forwarding on microk8s on mac m1

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I'm freshman on microk8s, and I'm trying out things by deploying a simple apache2 to see things working on my Mac M1:

```
◼ ~ $ microk8s kubectl run apache --image=ubuntu/apache2:2.4-22.04_beta --port=80
pod/apache created
◼ ~ $ microk8s kubectl get pods
NAME                                   READY   STATUS             RESTARTS       AGE
apache                                 1/1     Running            0              5m37s
◼ ~ $ microk8s kubectl port-forward pod/apache 3000:80
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:3000 -> 80
```

but:

```
◼ ~ $ curl http://localhost:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000 after 5 ms: Connection refused
```

I've also tried to use a service:

```
◼ ~ $ microk8s kubectl expose pod apache --type=NodePort  --port=4000 --target-port=80
service/apache exposed
◼ ~ $ curl http://localhost:4000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000 after 3 ms: Connection refused
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I haven't figured it out, if I port-forward right within the VM by opening a shell via multipass, it does work. Next, you simply have to point to the VM's IP:

within a VM's shell:

```
ubuntu@microk8s-vm:~$ sudo microk8s kubectl port-forward service/hellopg 8080:8080 --address="0.0.0.0"
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:8080 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8080

ubuntu@microk8s-vm:~$ ifconfig enp0s1
enp0s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.64.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.64.255
        inet6 fde3:1a04:ba31:1209:5054:ff:fea9:9cf4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
```

from the host:

```
 curl http://192.168.64.2:8080/hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                   7
{"status": "how you doing?", "env_var":"¡hola mundo!"}
```

it works. I guess the command via `microk8s` is not executed properly within the machine? If anybody can explain this I'll update the question

Comment: I have the same problem. This link gave me a little bit more understanding but did not answer all of the questions: https://itnext.io/microk8s-on-macos-98f1de3aa63e

Answer (score 0):

**Microk8’s**  acts the same as kuberentes. So, it's better to create a Service with **NodePort**. This would expose your apache.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-apache
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: apache
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30004
```

Change the selector as per your requirement. For more detailed information to create NodePort service refer to this [official document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport)
You can use **ingress** as well. But in your case only for testing you can go with **NodePort**

Comment: I've tried it , unsuccessfully. I'll edit the question to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you to test it would be adding: **externalIPs** to you service.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.56.100 #your cluster IP
```

Happy coding!